# Convert files with React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, converters

I'm looking for a lib, or ressources to learn (if it's possible), to convert a file from a format A to a format B. I've been searching but nothing came up. So I have a few questions:

- Is there any existing librairies, or tutorials that can accomplish
  that ?
- According to your knowledge, do you know if it's even possible ?
- If I have to do it myself, where should I start ?

**EDIT : I would especially like to convert videos (probably .mp4) to .gif.**

Thanks for reading,

Comment: From which to what format? There probably are some libs / tutorials, but you could elaborate your question a little.

Comment: Hey, sorry, I edited my question to add that info. Thanks !